# JQuery fadeIn() not working despite correct log messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

**Hey guys!**

I have a little problem in my recent built homepage. I tried to fade in the HTML div with the class "content" and it put out both log messages into the console but it's still not fading in!

**I, of course, removed all not needed information in those code snippets**

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="content">  </div>
```

And my CSS

```
.content{
margin: 0px;
position: fixed;
display:none
background-image: url("../img/city_topdown_blurred.png");
background-size:cover;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

and finally my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("fading in");
  $('.content').fadeIn("slow", function(){
    console.log("fading done");
  });
});
```

Both log messages are instantly pushed out to my browser (Chrome)
even if the time is set to 10000 or higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `;` after `display: none` adding that back in seems to fix it, here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/nbekm981/1

The reason the missing `;` broke it was because it was setting `display: none background-image: url("../img/city_topdown_blurred.png");` which is invalid. Because it was invalid it went with the default `display: block;` (which is automatically visible). So your fade in was already complete before it started in a way.

Comment: oh yeah didn't see it

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon after `display:none;`

Also, the image (for the background) might take a bit to load so you might want to pre-load the image before fading it in.

See **running demo below**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // pre-load the image
  $('<img/>').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/1024/1024').load(function() {
    console.log("image done loading");
    // prevent memory leaks
    $(this).remove();

    // assign image to .content 
    $('.content').css('background-image', 'url(http://lorempixel.com/1024/1024)');

    console.log("fading in starts");
    // fade in 
    $('.content').fadeIn(2000, function() {
      console.log("fading done");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  /*background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1024/1024");
    background-color: green;*/
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

From jQuery documentation

> The .fadeIn() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. It is similar to the .fadeTo() method but that method does not unhide the element and can specify the final opacity level.

I don't believe it will animate with `display: none`, but with `opacity: 0`.

Comment: "It is similar to the `.fadeTo()` method but that method does not unhide the element" - that method being the `.fadeTo()` - Whereas the .`fadeIn()` method does 'unhide' the element so it will change its `display` attribute... that's how I interpret it

Comment: it was just the semicolon missing